# Unable to read /proc/pid/stack file even with proper permissions

Tags: linux, files, proc

As far as i know, i should be able to read a regular file contents if i have the permissions to do so.

Following is the output of **ls -l stack** for the **stack** file (/proc/pid/stack) for one of the processes running of my Linux system :

**-r--r--r-- 1 Usr1 Usr1 0 Sep 20 18:08 stack**

Looking at the permissions, i should be able to read that file.

Although whenever i try to read the file (**vi stack**) as **Usr1**, it shows nothing but an empty file.At the same time i get the following output when i try to open the file as a **root** user.

[] ptrace_stop+0x154/0x270
[] get_signal_to_deliver+0x3dc/0x610
[] do_signal+0x3f/0x8d0
..
..
..

I am not able to figure out what exactly is going on ?

Comment: A few files in `/proc/$pid` have additional restrictions beyond the permissions, but this isn't the case for `stack`. Are you running in some kind of virtual environment (e.g. inside a container)? What kernel version are you running, on what distribution (or if you compiled it yourself, with what options)?

Comment: @Gilles .. It's not a virtual environment .Kernel version is : 3.8.0-19-generic ... I am using Linux mint .

Answer (score 4):

What's unusual here is that the `open` of `/proc/pid/stack` succeeds, but an attempt to `read` from it returns `EPERM`.

The kernel source code for showing the contents of `/proc/pid/stack`, `fs/proc/base.c:proc_pid_stack()`, calls `lock_trace()`, which will return a permission error if the caller doesn't have access to [ptrace](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man2/ptrace.2.html) the target process.

On many Linux distributions, there are Linux Security Modules that may restrict the use of `ptrace`. One of these is [Yama](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt), which you'll encounter if you use Ubuntu. Permission to use `ptrace` is restricted to root or to an ancestor (typically the parent) process of the target. You can check this with

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope 
1
```

And can disable it by doing

```
root@ubuntu:~# echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

Thereafter, you'll be able to `cat /proc/pid/stack`.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, that was very helpful .It worked for me. Just one thing, does read() system call behaves differently for different files ? . I mean for a normal file it is just going to fetch the contents from the disk,at the same time, as you mentioned for this file it is going to do few extra things.

Comment: @curious Unix and Linux support a variety of filesystem types that can implement read and write in their own unique ways. Virtually all of them just read and write from disk or from a remote system's disk, but some filesystem types like `/proc` (procfs), `/sys`, or [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), can generate data on the fly.

Comment: I have `0` in `ptrace_scope`, and also I can attach via GDB or `strace`, however, I still can't read that `stack` file, I still get `Permission denied`.